# Could not load file or assembly TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0

Tags: .net, azure-devops, specflow

Out of the blue since Tuesday with no code nor pipeline changes the build executed in Azure DevOps fails I get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41'

I actually see this attribute in the generated code: `[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "3.1.0.0")]` however I don't use explicitely version 3.1.0.0 of Specflow anywhere

these are packages that I have

[image]

Do you know what may cause this error?

Comment: did you check for any nuget package upgrade running as part of the build process and that a newer version of specflow was released. Also did you check if the dll reference is being set from the packages and not the `bin` directory.

Comment: @Saravanan I was able to mend it. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error exists due to MS Agents being updated with flawed .NET Core SDK. To solve this problem one has to add pipeline variable `MSBUILDSINGLELOADCONTEXT` with value `1`.

Comment: Great work! Thanks for sharing your solution here, please consider [Accepting it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. (A reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: For TeamCity where to add MSBUILDSINGLELOADCONTEXT with value 1 ?